# Java - SimpleDateFormat unexpected parsing behaviour

Tags: java, spring, date

I'm reading information from a file (.csv) that will be inserted to a database after validation and approval from the end user. The text file is read, validated and its information loaded to a List containing forms which are used to check if the data already exist in database.

The problem arises when parsing the String to Date. The SimpleDateFormat.parse() method returns an unexpected date format even when the pattern for SimpleDateFormat is "yyyy-MM-dd".

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
```

Parsing the loaded values to the travel object:

```
travel.setDate( dateFormat.parse( form.getTravelDate() ));
```

In debugger the form shows the date as:

```
"2012-12-12"
```

It is read as intended. However when parsed becomes:

```
Wed Dec 12 00:00:00 CST 2012
```

I've spent the whole day trying to solve this but I'm out of ideas at this point. Afaik the pattern is alright and I've tried adding a locale to no avail.

Edit: the problem is when I need to insert the values to the database using Hibernate. The not desired format also ends up showing in the Database.

The data is show in a .jsp page using

```
 HttpServletRequest("table",travelList);
```

The date format I don't need shows here, when in the past this issue never happened. At last the information is sent to the database where the problem persists.

Comment: Parsing (string to date) doesn't have anything to do with formatting (date to string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it "becomes" a `java.util.Date` value. If you're then converting it *back* to a string by calling `Date.toString()`, you should consult the `Date.toString()` documentation for what to expect.

The value stored in the `Date` is *just* a point in time - the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. There's no format in there, no time zone etc. It also doesn't know that it was only a date value rather than a date and time (the naming of `Date` is one of the *many* unfortunate aspects of the API).

It's crucial that you mentally separate "the result of the parse operation" from "the string value that is used to represent that result if I call `toString"`".

I'd also advise you to set the time zone on your `SimpleDateFormat` to UTC when parsing a date - that way you know that you can't *possibly* have any ambiguous or skipped times leading to hard-to-predict behaviour. (Of course, you then need to know that you'll have parsed the date to "the start of the UTC date" and handle it appropriately elsewhere.)

Comment: I get that it is different if I need to show the value, the problem is I don't need to show it.

    request.setAttribute("table",dateList)


Is the last thing I do before insertion which also carries out the same problem. 

Anyway, I'll try to set the UTC and see what comes out of it.

Comment: @lhuezo: What do you mean by "which also carries out the same problem"? You haven't described what the problem actually is - and we have no idea what `request` is here. If you're interested in a particular string representation, then you'll need to format the `Date` value appropriately.

Comment: When the insert operation occurs the date is inserted with the undesired format. About the request, sorry. I meant HttpServletRequest.setAttribute(). 

I'll check the Date representation, hope that is.

Comment: @lhuezo: What does the servlet have to do with the insert? What is it being inserted into? How is that request attribute used? You've left out *huge* amounts of context here.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be necessary to dwell into that part since it's strictly a problem occurring on the class used to load the file value. 

I mean that the information no longer needs any manipulation, after the parsing it is only show in a table and waiting for manual approval. But the table shows the incorrect format which is also carried out to the database when the data is approved.

Comment: @lhuezo: If the "table shows the incorrect format" and if you mean a database table, then you should give us more information about that. We don't know what the table schema is, or how you're inserting into it. But you still seem to be fixating on the parsing, as if a `Date` has a format, when it doesn't...

Comment: I mean a html table, then when it is approved the insert operation occurs. The insert is done via Hibernate, the DAO as the Service haven been tested to work. I get now that I'm expecting a format when there's none but the underlying problem remains. I can't find a way to insert the date as "yyyy-MM-dd" when loaded from file.

Comment: @lhuezo: Okay, if it's an HTML table then you're converting from a `Date` to a `String` in order to display the HTML, right? So find out where that conversion is taking place and fix it. We have no idea where that conversion is taking place, but you should be able to work it out.

Comment: I'm not sadly, the `HttpServletRequest.setAttribute(`) takes the whole list with the `Date` values, then the `ModelAndView()` method and that's it. When the content is approved I need to insert the information to the databse. The operation is successful but when I open SQLDeveloper the dates added from file are messed up, while the ones inserted using the normal method (user input in the jsp page) is formatted correctly. There's no difference in how the information is treated and sent to the databse, is just that the ones loaded from file show the full date instead of the short format.

Comment: @lhuezo: "and that's it" doesn't describe *at all* how the values are being displayed. If you don't know how it's being converted, might a colleague be able to help? At least they'd have more context than we do. And you still haven't told us the schema of the database, which doesn't help us to solve that aspect either. If it's meant to be a date, then the column should be a `DATE` column. It sounds like it *might* be a `VARCHAR` column, which would be another thing you should fix.

Comment: That's the last thing I do with the data. No further manipulation is done. Nothing from that point manipulates the data. 

Anyway, seems I have an entirely different problem altogether. I'll mark this as the answer since it gave me the most insight. 

Thankl!

Comment: @lhuezo: "Nothing from that point manipulates the data." That's clearly not true. You have a `java.util.Date`, but it is being converted into a `String`, which is being embedded in HTML. Do you understand that that *must* be happening? The `java.util.Date` itself isn't part of the HTML, is it? Now that's not to say that you've got any code which is explicitly doing the conversion - but *something* is doing it. But for the database side, again I urge you to look carefully at your schema.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the formatter when printing the `Date` as well.

```
dateFormat.format( travel.getDate() );
```

When your parse the `String` using a `DateFormat`, you get a complete `Date` object with the time units missing in the string initialized to zero. In your example, that's hours, minutes and seconds.

By default, if you do not use a formatter, `Date`'s default string representation (provided by its `toString()` method) gets printed.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing doesn't mean it format, it simply parse it as text to a `java.util.Date` object. See [parse method in documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)).

You need to use the `format` method.

```
dateFormat.format(travel.getDate())
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) for more details.

Comment: That's means I need to go back to a String and THEN back to a Date object?

Comment: @lhuezo No, you can directly skip the parse step and format directly travel.getDate()

Answer (score 0):

if `form.getTravelDate()` is returning String then  First `Parse` the Date from String

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date parsedDate=dateFormat.parse(form.getTravelDate()); 
// Here parsedDate is in form Wed Dec 12 00:00:00 CST 2012
```

Now Format the Date using the Same SImpleDateFormat to get the desired output

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(parsedDate));
```

Your Desired Output

```
2012-12-12
```

**Update**

Assuming data Type of Columns in which we insert this data in  Database is of `Date` Type not `varchar` then use the below statement

```
travel.setDate(dateFormat.format(parsedDate));
```

Comment: The problem is I don't need to show the value, I actually need to insert it to database with said format. 

I find strange than after parsing the String to Date I have to set it back to String.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `parse` method returns `Date`. Below is the parse method syntax.

```
public Date parse(String source)
           throws ParseException
```

So, you need to parse the string date and store into a Date variable. Then format the Date variable using `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
//getTravelDate is "2012-12-12"

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
Date dtObj=new Date(); 
dtObj=dateFormat.parse(form.getTravelDate());   //Store in date variable    
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(dtObj)); // Now format the date object
```

The final output will be `2012-12-12`. Hope it will help you.